Make smooth horizontal scroll navbar
I'm trying to create a smooth horizontal navbar. When I click a link in the navbar, I want the active link to automatically scroll into the center of the viewport. However, this functionality isn't working. Could you help me identify the issue in my JavaScript code? javascriptnavbar
My HTML
<div class="scrollmenu">
      <a href="#" class="active">Opening</a>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
      <a href="#">RSVP</a>
      <a href="#">Business</a>
      <a href="#">Gallery</a>
      <a href="#">Thanks</a>
    </div>

My CSS
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-inline: 50px;
  padding-block: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

My Javascript
let nav = document.querySelectorAll('scrollmenu');

if (nav) {
  let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('scrollmenu a');
  let activeLink = document.querySelector('.active');
  activeLink.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', inline: 'center' });

  navLinks.forEach(function (link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      navLinks.forEach(function (link) {
        link.classList.remove('active');
      });
      link.classList.add('active');
      link.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', inline: 'center' });
    });
  });
}

Identify the issue in my JavaScript code

href of the anchors need an Element to scroll to, e.g. #Agenda, with Agenda being the value of an Element ID somewhere on the page that you want to scroll into view.
